# Get fewest number of values that satisfies all keys

Tags: algorithm, go

Say I have one of two setups

```
map[int][]int{
  19: {1, 2},
  20: {2, 3},
  233: {3}
}
```

or

```
map[int][]int{
  1: {19},
  2: {19, 20},
  3: {20, 233},
}
```

I would like to get an output that is the fewest number of values that satisfies the keys (in the first example)

There are two valid outputs for this example `[]int{1, 3}` or `[]int{2,3}`

Another example:

In:

```
map[int][]int{
  18: {1}
  19: {1, 2},
  20: {2, 3},
  233: {3}
}
```

Out:
`[]int{1,3}`

I've looked into DFS, but can't seem to wrap my head around setting it up to be able to get the solution. Maybe this could also be a set cover problem.

Answer (score 3):

Each value is equivalent to the subset of the keys that it will satisfy.

You want the smallest set of values that cover all of the keys.

This is exactly the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem, which was one of the 21 original problems that were proven to be NP-complete.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is an efficient way of solving a set cover problem without essentially making all possible combination of answers and picking the one with the shortest length? It seems like you could use a DFS to solve the problem.

Comment: @swade NP complete means that, as far as we know, there is no general solution.  But the linked article describes several strategies that work well in practice.

Comment: This problem seems related, but not the same as the set cover problem as described on the Wikipedia article.  Could you explain how the problems are the same or equivalent somehow?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Starting with a set cover problem where a universe is covered by a set S of sets.  Make the universe into the keys of your data structure.  Map each key to the list of sets that contain that key.  And now you get a data structure of the above form such that the answer to the OP's question gives the answer to the original set cover problem.  Therefore the set cover problem reduces to the OP's question.  It isn't hard to construct the mapping the other way as well, and therefore the problems are equivalent.